# MuTect install: GATK-protected: maven: Java-compile-error

Tags: java, maven-3, gatk

I'm trying to install mutect, and as directed in the README.md, I've git cloned gatk-protected and tried to do 'mvn -Ddisable.queue install'. But I get the following issue. I've java 1.7 and maven 3.3.3.

```
     1.[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
     2.[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
     3.[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
     4.[ERROR] /home/krb/.../annotator/interfaces/AnnotationInterfaceManager.java:[129,24] no suitable method found for add(java.lang.Object)
     5.method java.util.Collection.add(T) is not applicable
     6.  (argument mismatch; java.lang.Object cannot be converted to T)
     7.method java.util.List.add(T) is not applicable
     8.  (argument mismatch; java.lang.Object cannot be converted to T)
     9.[INFO] 1 error
    10.[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
    11.[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
    12.[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (compile-java) on project gatk-framework: Compilation failure
    13.[ERROR] /home/krb/.../annotator/interfaces/AnnotationInterfaceManager.java:[129,24] no suitable method found for add(java.lang.Object)
    14.[ERROR] method java.util.Collection.add(T) is not applicable
    15.[ERROR] (argument mismatch; java.lang.Object cannot be converted to T)
    16.[ERROR] method java.util.List.add(T) is not applicable
    17.[ERROR] (argument mismatch; java.lang.Object cannot be converted to T)
    18.[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    19.org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (compile-java) on project gatk-framework: Compilation failure
    20./home/krb/.../annotator/interfaces/AnnotationInterfaceManager.java:[129,24] no suitable method found for add(java.lang.Object)
    21.method java.util.Collection.add(T) is not applicable
    22. (argument mismatch; java.lang.Object cannot be converted to T)
    23.method java.util.List.add(T) is not applicable
    24.  (argument mismatch; java.lang.Object cannot be converted to T)
```

I followed the readme file present [here.](https://github.com/broadinstitute/mutect)
Could anyone please help in resolving the issue?

Comment: Seems like your code doesn't compile. Can you share the sources for AnnotationInterfaceManager.java?

Comment: You might either want to provide some source or yet better ask in the relevant usergroups/forums.

Comment: @Mureinik I'm sorry for my ignorance, but can you tell me where to look for them?

Comment: @Thomas I've asked in the related forum, but I've not received any response from them.

Comment: @HobbitEesmereldatGoldworthy the error shows you the path: `/home/krb/Ramani/MUTECT/gatk-protected/public/gatk-framework/src/main/java/org/broadinstitute/sting/gatk/walkers/annotator/interfaces/AnnotationInterfaceManager.java`

Comment: What I meant was, what exactly should I show you? The entire file AnnotationInterfaceManager.java? @Mureinik

Comment: Yes we'd need to see that file's content, at least the relevant part of it. If that file is huge please post a link instead of dumping it all here. And _please provide line numbers_. Besides that, if you're having problems with compiling third party software I'd doubt SO is the right place to help. If you don't get any answers on the relevant forums then either first dig into the source yourself or file a bug report in their issue tracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `README.md` for mutect instructs to `git reset --hard 3.1` in the `gatk-protected` folder. I undid this action, which, my guess is, resulted in the use of the latest GATK-protected version. So, after I undid that reset command using `git reflog`, the procedure resumed and the mutect jar file was also successfully built.

Answer (score 2):

See this part in your stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
  /home/krb/Ramani/MUTECT/gatk-protected/public/gatk-framework/src/main/java/org/broadinstitute/sting/gatk/walkers/annotator/interfaces/AnnotationInterfaceManager.java:[129,24] no suitable method found for add(java.lang.Object)
    method java.util.Collection.add(T) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.Object cannot be converted to T)
    method java.util.List.add(T) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; java.lang.Object cannot be converted to T)
```

The `Collection.add(T)` is cannot be applied to `Object`.